# Is there a way to add another star to the Element ui ranking component? I want there to be six stars instead of five

Tags: laravel, element-ui

I'm trying to add another star to the Element-ui ranking component, is there a way to do this? I haven't been able to find anything on their [docs](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/rate). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `max` attribute for this, default is set to 5 stars:

the following code adds 6 stars

```
<el-rate :max="6"></el-rate>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/remul/pen/NWWryvB)